# PySpark MLLib APproximate nearest neighbour search for multiple keys

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, nearest-neighbor

I want to use [ANN from PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/ml-features.html#approximate-nearest-neighbor-search). I have a DataFrame of 100K keys for which I want to perform top-10 ANN searches on an already transformed Spark DataFrame. But it seems that [API of BucketedRandomProjectionLSH](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel.approxNearestNeighbors) expects only one key at a time. I also want to avoid using `approxSimilarityJoin`, because it only allows you to set a threshold, but this would lead to a variable `k` for each key (it also fails in my case saying that for some records there are no NNs for a given threshold).

Currently, the best thing I came up with is `.collect()` the keys and call `approxNearestNeighbors` in a for loop on the driver, but it is terribly inefficient.

Does anyone know how I can get top-10 ANN searches for my 100K keys in parallel?

Thank you.